# How to raise health points (HP) of heroes in Blacksmith Story HD (iOS)?

Tags: blacksmith-story

I've been playing this game for a few days, but I cannot figure out how to raise the heroes' HP. There are still many heroes with 20 or 40 HP. This is quite useless against level 30+ monsters.

Any ideas how I can raise the HP?